# Running javafx scene builder in terminal

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

I'm running wmii in linux and in wondering my self if you can run javafx scene builder from a terminal?

Answer (score 0):

You should download javafx scene builder for linux rather running it from terminal.

Here is the link to download scene builder for linux.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/sb2download-2177776.html

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I was not clear with a question. I have instaled this for linux but I was wondering if there is a command for starting scene builder from a terminal with a command...

Answer (score 0):

The oracle don't support JavaFX 8 so the latest Scene builder is supported by Gluon: [Latest SceneBuilder](http://gluonhq.com/open-source/scene-builder/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm late, but in case anyone has this question:

If you're trying to run scene builder from the terminal you more than like installed it as a snap (AFAIK snap wasn't out when this question was originally asked but this is likely the case now). Scene builder installs itself to `/opt/scenebuilder/`. You can verify this if you have the locate command by running `updatedb` then `locate SceneBuilder`.

If you run `/opt/scenebuilder/bin/SceneBuilder` you can execute the program from the terminal.

Snaps can be difficult to find the executables for, so having the locate command is very handy!